# Wordpress REST API - How do I create an API route with empty namespace?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have an API with a route https://example.com/wp-json/videos. This was created with the [JSON rest API plugin](https://github.com/rmccue/WP-API) and I need to re-create it with the WP Rest API as the plugin stopped working.

I found that with WP rest API, I cannot create a route with an empty namespace or route so that I can have only

```
/videos
```

in the api route.

How can I do this?

I tried this code

```
function handle_routes($rest ) {
    $video_api = new Video_API;
    $routes = $video_api->register_routes();
    foreach ($routes as $route => $data) {
        $namespace = explode( '/', trim($route, '/'))[0];
        $rest->register_route($namespace, $route, [
            'methods'  => $data[0][1],
            'callback' => $data[0][0] 
        ]);
    }
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'handle_routes', 10, 1);
```

All the parameters are correct but it gives a rest_no_route error so the routes are not registered.

```
$routes['/videos/(?P<id>\d+)'] = array(
    array( array( $this, 'get_video'), WP_JSON_Server::READABLE)
);
```

This is one example of route sent to the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, this should do what you are asking.

```php
add_action('rest_api_init', function($rest) {
    $rest->register_route('videos', '/videos', [
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => '' //<--your callback function for videos
    ]);
});
```

What is happening here is you are adding a new route directly to the `WP_REST_Server` object and it creates a route with an empty namespace.

Comment: Thanks it works for one. I tried generalising it to handle all other routes but it does not work. I have updated my question with the code I tried. Can you take a look?

Comment: I would be happy to help you but I'm not sure exactly what you are asking for right now. What other routes are you trying to handle?

Comment: I was using the JSON rest api plugin (link in the question) before so all those routes I need to change to use WP rest api now

Comment: Got it. The issue was with the method not being set correctly. It was setting to 1 instead of 'GET' but I thought that would have worked. Anyways thanks alot